# TBB: Differing measures for the same work?

Tags: c++, std, tbb

I have a simple TBB `parallel_for` loop that I'm trying to time, and do some other measurements. The simple loop and timing initially looked like this:

```
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tbb_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, values.size()),
    [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r)
    {
        for (int i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i)
        {
            values[i] = std::sin(i * 0.001);
        }
    });
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tbb_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> loop_duration = (tbb_end - tbb_start);
```

The time measured is about `2ms`. Now, I need to add some data collection in here, and consequently need to time just the loop. So, I altered it to this:

```
    std::atomic<double> parallel_time = 0;
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, values.size()),
    [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r)
    {
        int worker_index = tbb::task_arena::current_thread_index();
        int range = r.end() - r.begin();

        mtx.lock();
        thread_work_amount[worker_index] += range;
        mtx.unlock();

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tbb_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i)
        {
            values[i] = std::sin(i * 0.001);
        }
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> tbb_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> loop_duration = (tbb_end - tbb_start);
        double foo = parallel_time.load();
        foo += loop_duration.count();
        parallel_time.store(foo);
    });
```

Outputting `parallel_time` shows a total time of `12ms`, but how? I should only be measuring the loops, and per the first measurement, that should only have been `2ms`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Unless `r` is huge, I don't think either of those measurements is meaningful.

Comment: The ```values``` variable is a vector of ```1,000,000``` doubles. Not sure how that works out when TBB partitions things.

Comment: How many calls to your lambda do you get?  It is possible you're accumulating fractions of ms that just happen to span clock ticks.

Comment: I stuck a simple counter in the lambda (```std::atomic<unsigned int>```) and it said it was hit `5641` times.

Comment: There is a data race in the body of `parallel_for`. Two or more threads can load, sum, and consequently store their own values to `parallel_time` simultaneously, since this memory is not guarded, though manipulated atomically.

Comment: I don’t understand, ```parallel_time``` is an ```std::atomic``` and should be protected, no?

Comment: The first version of the code measures the span (critical path).  The second version (if the logical race pointed out by @AlekseiFedotov does not happen) measures the total work.

Comment: To understand the logical race, consider if `parallel_time` is initially zero.  If two threads almost simultaneously load from it, they both see zero.  They then each add their contribution to zero, and then each does a store.  The second store overwrites the effect of the first store.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you are correct! How then can I measure just the span of work without the time taken by the data collection?

Comment: `std::atomic<double>` supports atomic arithmetic operations, so you should just do `parallel_time += loop_duration.count()`